# mongoDB union-like compoundIndex

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hi my db look like this:

```
Team: {
    subteam1: {
       members: [
          { age: 23, exp: 5 },
          { age: 25, exp: 2 }
       ]
    },
    subteam2: {
        members: [
          { age: 33, exp: 12 },
          { age: 54, exp: 31 }
       ]
    },
}
```

I want to create mongo index such as i can find team by members' (age,exp)
I can use compoundIndex("subteam1.members.age","subteam1.members.exp") but thats only for subteam1. How can i do it for both subteams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query both subTeams members by age AND exp you will need to change the schema this way:

```
Team: {
  members: [
    { subTeam: "subteam1", age: 23, exp: 5 },
    { subTeam: "subteam1", age: 25, exp: 2 },
    { subTeam: "subteam2", age: 33, exp: 12 },
    { subTeam: "subteam2", age: 54, exp: 31 }
  ]
}
```

Then you can add an index `{ "members.age": 1", "members.exp": 1 }`.

Mind that this index will only support queries that inlcude its prefix (`members.age`).
That is it won't help if you want to query only by `members.exp`, you'll need to add another single field index for that.

---

Alternatively you can create wildcard index

```
db.Team.createIndex(
  { "$**" : 1 },
  { "wildcardProjection" :
    {
      "subteam1.members.age" : 1,
      "subteam1.members.exp" : 1,
      "subteam2.members.age" : 1,
      "subteam2.members.exp" : 1
    }
  }
)
```

But it will only support single field queries,
that is querying subTeams members exclusively by age or exp.

Comment: I was thinking about "$**.members.age","$**.member.exp" im not sure if thats how it works tbh?

Comment: @ziyiyituxe Thanks for the hint with wildcard indexes. Unfortunately the option you just mentioned won't work, but I've updated my answer with possible wildcard index that should do the trick.

Comment: Could you tell me why its not gonna work? Also, i was wondering whats gonna happen if the members array gonna be empy?

Comment: @ziyiyituxe as per MongoDB docs you can create wildcard index 1) on a field; 2) on all fields. "$**.members.age" is none of them. As for your second question - it won't hurt if the array is empty, all will work as expected, no error will be thrown. I again updated my answer, please check